# "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" during OAuth 2.0 callback request

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, spotify

I'm quite new to Python 3 and Flask, and I'm currently building a simple web application to consume data from the Spotify API.

The OAuth 2.0 authentication flow is almost working since I'm able to call **https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize** and **https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token**.

At some point I need to request a new access and refresh token:

```
authentication_token = request.args['code']
code_payload = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": str(authentication_token),
    "redirect_uri": REDIRECT_URI
}
encoded_oauth2_tokens = base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))        
headers = {"Authorization": "Basic {}".format(encoded_oauth2_tokens)}
post_request = requests.post(SPOTIFY_TOKEN_URL, data=code_payload, headers=headers)
```

The callback request function is failing with the following error:

```
File "app.py", line 52, in callback
            encoded_oauth2_tokens = base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
          File "/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
            encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
        TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I understand that a string is being passed to `b64encode()`, but I'm not sure how can I change it to binary(?).

During my research most similar errors were related to opening files, and this is not my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because python3 strings are unicode, they need to be encoded before being passed to things that operate on a byte level (such as base64 encoding):

```
base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET).encode())
```

The default encoding is UTF-8, which should be sufficient for OAuth. The encode method accepts an argument to specify which encoding to use should that be necessary for your application: `"foo".encode("latin-1")`